Supabase - Check if row is defined, insert if not, not working
I am learning Supabase with NextJS and when a user is authenticated, I want to create a row with the auth user in my users table. I am able to do so successfully, but the logic keeps running and keeps trying to add a user to the user table even if they exist. This is what I currently have in my component:
useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const {
        data: { user },
      } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

      setUser(user);

      if (user.id) {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
          .from("users")
          .select("id")
          .eq("id", user.id);

       
        if (data.length === 0) {
          const { data, error } = await supabase.from("users").insert({
            id: user?.id,
            domainConnect: false,
            email: user?.email,
            isPremium: false,
            sites: [],
          });

          console.log("in data: ", data);
        }
      }
    };

    getUser();
  }, []);

My if (user.id) runs but I am unable to get the user from my db. It returns Array [] even though the ids match in my supabase.auth.getUser() to my user table id but the user isn't returned. Which means that if (data.length === 0) gets run and it tries to add a new user but since its a duplicate, it fails.
Am I setting my query up incorrectly to retrieve a user from my db?

What does setUser(user) do? Do you have another variable called user?

const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

Maybe try to change this (const [stateUser, setStateUser] = useState(null) f.ex.) so you don't have a mix of variables. It should not happen but you'll never know...

Have you set the RLS policies so that your user can query the public.users table?
